# Displacement does not work do you have any idea how to fix it

Tags: node-editor, displacement

[image: Displacment does not work do you have any idea how to fix it]

Displacment does not work do you have any idea how to fix it

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: to add to common_goldfish's answer, don't forget to work in Cycles, and in the Material > Settings > Surface > Displacement, choose Displacement Only for example

Answer (score 1):

Up on the top right, viewport shading, switch to **rendered** view.  I think you will probably see it.[image]

[image]